# No puedo acceder a los métodos de una clase CI 3.1.3

Tags: codeigniter

Compañeros, este problema nunca me había surgido, quiero accesar a un método de una clase desde CI y no me permite, les platico que recién descargue la versión CI 3.1.3, agregue el siguiente metodo al controlador que tiene por defecto:

**Welcome.php**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function hola()
    {
        echo "hola hola";
    }
}
```

posteriormente quiero entrar desde url en mi localhost:
*http://localhost/proyecto/index.php/welcome/hola/*

Pero en su lugar me regresa al localhost (raíz del server).

**Nota:** Cuando agrego el metodo en el **routes.php**, si accesa correctamente: `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome/hola';`

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Colegas alguien tiene alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En CodeIgniter 3 los nombres de los archivos controladores debe ir la primera letra mayúscula en este caso `Welcome.php`

Intenta acceder con esta url: `http://localhost/proyecto/index.php/Welcome/hola/`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome/hola';
```

Comment: Jesus, te la prolongaste... Así ya puede accesar via URL.